# VM export to OVA failed on vSphere Client 5.5

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx, export

If I want to export a VM on the vSphere Client to an OVA-File I get the error-message "Operation timed out". The VM has a size of ~3.5TB - I think thats the main problem because all other exports are successful. Is there a workaround or something else to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to export it using the PowerCLI cmdlet [`Export-VApp`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI51/html/Export-VApp.html). I found it to be more robust than the vSphere- and WebUI-Clients.

```
Get-VM hugevm |Export-VApp -Destination "C:\Destination"
```

Don't let the name of the cmdlet fool you, it's not only for VApps, it works with single VMs as well.

Comment: I will try and give a quick response here, if its successful